# Good list of references and books on statistical approximation, simulation and computational methods?

Tags: references, inference, simulation, computational-statistics, approximation

I am looking for books and resources that cover simulation and approximation techniques so that we do not have to follow the strict assumptions held by the many statistical models.  With how fast computers are these days, I think it'll be nice to get a good grasp of these techniques.  Lets just take the typical linear regression for example.

There are many assumptions behind that model, but arguably the two most important are independent observations and Y | X follows a normal distribution.  I know in Bayesian methods, we are able to relax the normality assumption.  Y | X can follow any distribution and we are able to simulate the posterior distribution of our betas and other parameters of interest.  I forgot the exact process but we often look at the HDI instead of the 95% confidence interval for our estimates.

I am looking for a book or resource that covers similar techniques and answers some of the following questions:

- Given your own set of assumptions (i.e. non-normality, maybe some serial correlation), how do we generate unbiased estimates of our parameters of interest, create "confidence intervals" or similar metric like HDIs, and most importantly perform statistical inference...purely using computational methods.
- It may be hard to determine what is biased/unbaised without an analytical proof, but what are techniques to test if our estimate is likely to be biased or not.  I've heard people talk about bootstrap resampling as a way to produce our own sampling distributions but I don't know of a good indepth look at that technique.
- How do we measure how far off our approximation techniques are from precise analytical results?
- Common simulation methods like Gibbs sampling, MCMC, etc... and how they can be used?
- And just general approximation and simulation techniques that allow us bypass the need for analytical solutions (and solve equations that may not be closed formed).

I guess another example of what I am looking for is - in some models like in finance, for example pricing of options, we have analytical solutions.  For example black scholes is a closed form solution to pricing options.  But then you get into more customized derivatives and there really is no closed form solution - so you would want to use simulation methods to price it.  I am looking for more books on just simulation and computation methods for statistical inference so that you can build more custom models an customize the assumptions of your model.

Thanks!